# Encontrar el mínimo de un string pero "min()" elige un número que no es el mínimo

Tags: python

Necesito solucionar un problema donde se me da un string con números, por ejemplo "-1 -9 -4 2 8" y debo encontrar el mínimo.

Intenté corriendo lo siguiente:

```
min("-1 -9 -4".split())
```

Increíblemente el output da `"-1"` en lugar de `"-9"` y no sé cuál es la razón. Quizás haya una mejor manera de solucionarlo pero quiero entender por que Python evita seleccionar `"-9"`

Comment: Por más que hagas un `split` de la cadena, los elementos siguen siendo cadenas y no números, prueba con `min([int(n) for n in "-1 -9 -4".split()])`

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

La solución es igual a las propuestas por Patricio y por Marcos pero la explicación estaba mal así que aclaro por qué te devuelve `'-1'`.

Cuando utilizas la función `min()` se te pasó convertir los valores a número (Como puso Patricio en su comentario).

La razón por la que te devuelve "-1" es por que al comparar cadenas de caracteres, lo que hace `min()` es ver el valor [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) de cada caracter y devuelve el mínimo en cuanto a esos valores.

Por ejemplo, si tu cadena tuviera "A a" e hicieras `min("A a".split())` te va a devolver `'A'`, ya que el valor ASCII de "A" es 65 y el valor ASCII de "a" es 97, por lo tanto el "menor" es 65, que corresponde a `'A'`.

Por lo que al comparar "-1 -9 -4" primero ve que todos empiezan con "-" y luego compara el caracter del dígito, pero ese dígito también es `string` por lo que devuelve 1 ya que su valor ASCII es 49 y es menor a los otros dos caracteres.

La solución, tal como lo pusieron Patricio y Marcos es convertir a enteros:

Utilizando comprensión de listas sería:

```
min([int(n) for n in "-1 -9 -4".split()])
```

Y utilizando un ciclo `for`

```
split = "-1 -9 -4".split()

a = list()

for i in split:
    a.append(int(i))
    
print(min(a))
```

Comment: También, para ahorrar memoria y velocidad puedes usar comprensión de generador (que es más complejo que la comprensión de listas): `min(int(n) for n in "-1 -9 -4".split())`

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que cuando haces `split` a una cadena de carácter pues lo que obtienes es una arreglo de valores `string` y como no tiene como validar cual es el mínimo pues te devuelve al valor el la mínima posición del arreglo, o sea en la posición 0 y ese valor es el '-1'.

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir esos valores en `int` o el tipo de datos numérico que desees, y de ahí hacer el `min()`

```
split = "-1 -9 -4".split()

a = list()

for i in split:
    a.append(int(i))
    
    
print(min(a))
```

Con esto, tu resultado será `-9`

Comment: Buen día, la explicación del mínimo está mal, no importa el orden que pongas el `string` te va a devolver -1